# Interacting with TFS using PHP

Tags: php, tfs

I need to develop an module that interact with TFS for our internal office application, but the project is in php, i have done searching a lot, but could not find a sdk or api in php that could do the following.

1. listing the work items for a tfs user
2. creating / modifying work items.
3. View work item details and get attachments
4. modifying work items

can anybody suggest an api / sdk that could do the above said actions,

note: we are not interacting with Visual Studio Online, we are using hosted tfs in our own premises.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Java SDK for TFS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616) and the [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) and then try something like this (psuedo code only)

```
<?php  
require_once("java/Java.inc");
$tfsTPC=new java("com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSTeamProjectCollection","http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");  
$projects = $tfsTPC->getWorkItemClient()->getProjects();
?>
```

P.S. My PHP knowledge died a long time ago, so I'm not sure if the sample code is quite right, but hopefully you get the idea.

Also, even though it's the Java SDK you're using you should be able to follow all the C# samples since the SDK methods are almost identical between the .NET and Java SDKs